# IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured

Tags: java, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I'm trying to use google vision in google api, however I have the following problem:

> jun 07, 2017 8:50:00 AM io.grpc.internal.ChannelExecutor drain
>   ADVERTÊNCIA: Runnable threw exception in ChannelExecutor
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been
>   properly configured.  at
>   io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:174)
>     at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:151)
>     at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.configure(GrpcSslContexts.java:139)
>     at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.forClient(GrpcSslContexts.java:109)
>     at
>   io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.createProtocolNegotiatorByType(NettyChannelBuilder.java:335)
>     at
>   io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.createProtocolNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:308)
>     at
>   io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory$DynamicNettyTransportParams.getProtocolNegotiator(NettyChannelBuilder.java:499)
>     at
>   io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.newClientTransport(NettyChannelBuilder.java:448)
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.newClientTransport(CallCredentialsApplyingTransportFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.startNewTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:209)
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.InternalSubchannel.obtainActiveTransport(InternalSubchannel.java:186)
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$SubchannelImplImpl.obtainActiveTransport(ManagedChannelImpl.java:806)
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.getTransportFromPickResult(GrpcUtil.java:568)
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientTransport.reprocess(DelayedClientTransport.java:296)
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl$5.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:724)
>     at io.grpc.internal.ChannelExecutor.drain(ChannelExecutor.java:87)
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$LbHelperImpl.runSerialized(ManagedChannelImpl.java:715)
>     at
>   io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListenerImpl.onUpdate(ManagedChannelImpl.java:752)
>     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$1.run(DnsNameResolver.java:174)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I'm trying to run the api's own sample code, below:

```
public class QuickstartSample {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Instantiates a client
        ImageAnnotatorClient vision = ImageAnnotatorClient.create();

        // The path to the image file to annotate
        String fileName = "./resources/wakeupcat.jpg";

        // Reads the image file into memory
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        ByteString imgBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

        // Builds the image annotation request
        List<AnnotateImageRequest> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        Image img = Image.newBuilder().setContent(imgBytes).build();
        Feature feat = Feature.newBuilder().setType(Type.LABEL_DETECTION).build();
        AnnotateImageRequest request = AnnotateImageRequest.newBuilder().addFeatures(feat).setImage(img).build();
        requests.add(request);

        // Performs label detection on the image file
        BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = vision.batchAnnotateImages(requests);
        List<AnnotateImageResponse> responses = response.getResponsesList();

        for (AnnotateImageResponse res : responses) {
            if (res.hasError()) {
                System.out.printf("Error: %s\n", res.getError().getMessage());
                return;
            }

            for (EntityAnnotation annotation : res.getLabelAnnotationsList()) {
                annotation.getAllFields().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s : %s\n", k, v.toString()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-vision</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev357-1.22.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-vision</artifactId>
        <version>0.17.2-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```

Has anyone ever had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually discovered that to run the api, you must necessarily be in a web context and also be running the application on a Jetty server